# Generating a url with the same GET parameters as the current page in a Django template

Tags: python, django

I have a certain link to a url in a Django template. I would like to grab all the GET parameters of the current page url and add them to the url of the template's link. The current page might have zero GET parameters.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Include the [`django.core.context_processors.request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request) context processor in your `settings.py`, then use the `request` object in your template's links:

```
<a href="{% url 'my_url' %}?{{ request.META.QUERY_STRING }}">
```

This will cause links from a page without any GET variables to have a trailing `?` but that's harmless. If that's not acceptable, you could test for them first:

```
<a href="{% url 'my_url' %}{% if request.META.QUERY_STRING %}?{{ request.META.QUERY_STRING }}{% endif %}">
```

Answer (score 3):

you could pass `request.META['QUERY_STRING']` to the template.

You can grab the get params before you render the template and pass them to the template and render them on the correct link.

You could also build a query string from `request.GET`

Answer (score 1):

The GET parameters of the current request are stored in [HTTPRequest.Get](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET).